# Scrolling is very choppy in UITableView when loading images

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uitableview, swift

I am creating an application that Holds about 26 images inside of a structure, and then I load those images into a table view, and anytime a new image comes into the View of the simulator, there is a bit of lag. It is definitely a problem dealing with loading images inside of the Table View.

I think I need to add an async, but I have no idea how to do that. If someone could guide me in the right direction on what I should do to achieve smooth scrolling, that would be awesome!

I wish I could post a photo, but I don't have a good enough reputation on StackOverFlow.com.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var question : Question

    question = Questions[indexPath.row]

    var titleLabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel

    titleLabel.text = question.name

    var backgroundImage = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(5) as UIImageView

    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: question.pic)

    var frame : CGRect = CGRectMake(0, backgroundImage.frame.size.height - 200, backgroundImage.frame.size.width, backgroundImage.frame.size.height - 200)

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    return cell

}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to load thumbnail size images in uitableviewcell. Look at the memory graph also how it is behaving i guess it would go beyond 50 mb. Your scrolling is lagging because heavy memory usage. If you still want to use fullsize image I would recommend you to load activity indicator and load images in background in memory. Once image is loaded  call GCD main_queue method to load the image. This way your scrolling will not be lagging anymore

Comment: Please post the code where you're loading the images/

Comment: @Shashi3456643 Oh! my memory usage was about 307 MB. I forgot to check that. I will definitely see what happens when I change the size of the Images.

Comment: @LyndseyScott self.Questions = [Question(name:"First Table", pic:"1001_SJ05091-L.jpg"),
            Question(name:"Second Table", pic:"image.jpg"),
            Question(name:"Third Table", pic:"1016_8D10529-X2.jpg")] This was the code that loads the images in order to use them.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the size of the images. Use a smaller thumbnails for the tableView cells. Convert your images smaller for it.

```
CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(160, 160);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height)];
UIImage *thumbnailImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what my issue was too.  I ended up adding some code that makes the width/height a bit more dynamic.  I added it in an answer below, but gave you props.

Comment: Does this support concurrent thumbnail image creation? it seems like the image contexts would overlap...

Answer (score 0):

Kreuzberg's answer solved my problem, as I was getting jerky performance even with GCD and main_queue implemented.  Since I can't add too much code in comments, I expanded on his answer so the width/height could be a bit more dynamic.

```
if (image.size.width > MAX_THUMBNAIL_RESOLUTION || image.size.height > MAX_THUMBNAIL_RESOLUTION) {
    int width;
    int height;
    CGFloat ratio = image.size.width/image.size.height;

    if (ratio > 1) {
        width = MAX_THUMBNAIL_RESOLUTION;
        height = width / ratio;
    }
    else {
        height = MAX_THUMBNAIL_RESOLUTION;
        width = height * ratio;
    }

    CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height)];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

You can make the constant MAX_THUMBNAIL_RESOLUTION to be anything you think reasonable.  Or, you can calculate screen density and use a multiplier.